# Symplectic group action

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold. We say that a group action $\phi: G \times M \rightarrow M$ is symplectic if each $\phi(g,.)$ is a symplectomorphism.

Now, I am going through some lecture notes that are not available online, where I have difficulties to understand some details.

So we define the vector field $\psi$ on the Lie Algebra ($\eta \in \mathfrak{g},p \in M$) such that $$\psi(\eta)(p) = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} (\phi(e^{t \eta},p)) \in T_pM$$

So far so good. Now the author says: Assume that for each $\psi(\eta)$ there is a global Hamilton function $H_{\eta}: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $dH_{\eta} = \omega(\psi_{\eta},.).$ (So $\psi_\eta$ is the Hamiltonian vector field to $dH_{\eta}.)$
So far so good:

Now the author wants to show that

$H_{\xi} ( \phi(g,p)) = H_{Ad_{g^{-1}}(\xi)}(p)$ for all $g \in G$ and $\xi \in \mathfrak{g}.$

In order to do this he claims that it is sufficient to prove this for all $1-$parameter subgroups $g(t) = e^{t \eta}, \eta \in \mathfrak{g}.$

I have no idea why this is sufficient cause I don't see that the exponential map is surjective in general (despite, he may refer here to a special case. at least, this is what I suspect, maybe you can help me identifying this one.)

Then he writes $H_{\xi} ( \phi(g,p)) = H_{Ad_{g^{-1}}(\xi)}(p)$ if and only if

$H_{\xi} ( \phi(e^{t \eta},p)) = H_{Ad_{e^{-t\eta}}(\xi)}(p).$

and after that he again claims that it is sufficient (I have not the slightest idea why) to show this for $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}$ so he differentiates both sides and gets for the right hand-side

$$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}H_{Ad_{e^{-t\eta}}(\xi)}(p) = H_{ad_{-\eta}(\xi)}(p).$$
Actually, I have even difficulties to understand why you can differentiate this function and leave $H$ as it is (no chain rule).

Later on, he claims that any $T_p(orb_G(p))$ can be written as $\psi_{\eta}(p)$ for some $\eta \in \mathfrak{g}$ where $orb_G(p)$ is the orbit of $p$ under the group action $g$. I think this is similar to the previous issues.

Either he likes to proof only special cases or I am missing a point here, but I don't see where all his sufficiency arguments come from? Is there anybody who looks through this or could comment on this?

I can talk to the author soon, but I don't want to contact him without being sure that there is really something missing here.

Comment: Any conditions on your Lie group? Is it compact?

Answer (score 1):

You should complain to them, since this result is simply wrong.  Consider how $\mathbb{R}^2$ acts on itself by translating with the usual symplectic form.  The functions $x$ and $y$ are Hamiltonian functions for generators of the Lie algebra (you can work this out; I'll just get bogged down into notation), and since the adjoint action is trivial, you should get that these are invariant, which is obviously false.  The correct theorem is that $H_\xi(\phi(g,p))$ is a Hamiltonian function for $\mathrm{Ad}_{g^{-1}}\xi$, but you can't consistently choose these in a way that's equivariant.  But I don't see this showing up in any of the issues you point out.

> I have no idea why this is sufficient cause I don't see that the exponential map is surjective in general (despite, he may refer here to a special case. at least, this is what I suspect, maybe you can help me identifying this one.)

This is sufficient because the image of the exponential map generates the group; so an arbitrary group element is a product of exponentials, and you can use this calculation multiple times.

> after that he again claims that it is sufficient (I have not the slightest idea why)

Because differentiating at $t=a$ is the same as replacing $p$ by $e^{a\eta}p$, and doing the differentiation.

> Actually, I have even difficulties to understand why you can differentiate this function and leave H as it is (no chain rule).

There's no chain rule because there's no differentiation in the space direction.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one question: This is a general result that any Lie group is generated by the exponential map?

Comment: @wewasss Yes, any connect group is generated by the image of the exponential map (the group generated by this image is always connected).  More generally, any open subset containing the identity in a connected Lie group generates the group (you can prove the subset it generates is both closed and open).